# Feynman nested loop diagrams

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-feynman, feynman

I am trying to reproduce the following Feynman diagrams:

[image]
[image]
[image]

and facing with some difficulties. It would be great to have some hints how to deal with these kinds of diagrams, i.e. with second and higher order loops (three-, four- etc nested loops) in a single
vertex.

I have tried to use loop and looseness, but it doesn't look right

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[compat=1.1.0]{tikz-feynman}

\begin{document}

\feynmandiagram [layered layout, horizontal=a to b] {
a [dot] -- [fermion] b [dot] -- [photon, loop, min distance=2cm] b,
a -- [photon, half left] b,
};
+
\feynmandiagram [layered layout, horizontal=a to b] {
a [dot] -- [fermion] b [dot],
a -- [photon, half left, looseness=0.5] b,
b -- [photon, half right, looseness=1] a,
a -- [photon, half left, looseness=1.5] b,
};


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have. See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. So, I edited the question and indicated my code and attached the result that I got.